# React setState not working with websocket

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I'am receiving messages from from a websocket,after which i have to update my state i've gone past previous questions and tried adding a callback to my setState however it still doesn't seem to work

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
    bus: [5, 6]}

}


render() {

    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://-------:5055");
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const state = this.state;
    const props = this.props;

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
     
      this.setState({
        bus: e.data
      },()=>console.log( state.bus)
      );
 
    };
```

note if i console log the message received i.e e.data it does show that the message was received , i get that the setState is Asynchronous but shouldn't it work if i added the callback to it

Answer (score 1):

In this configuration you are creating new websocket connection on each render of the component. You have to move connecting to the `componentDidMount` hook

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://-------:5055");
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const state = this.state;
    const props = this.props;

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      this.setState({ bus: e.data }, () => console.log(state.bus));
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    // only JSX
    return <div>...</div>
  }
```

This will make sure that you have only single connection.

Comment: oh man thanks a bunch ,haha i feel so stupid for not thinking about that , am sure that should be the solution , thanks again :)